# Paper Toolbar javascript not reacting

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a Polymer `paper-toolbar` element that takes some custom attributes like background-color and titles. It contains a.o. a search button and is called in various other elements.
The problem is that only the element where it is first called will display the search box when toggled while in other elements it does not.

This is the code for the toolbar:

```
<template>
    <paper-toolbar class$="{{toolbarSize}}" style$="background-color:{{toolbarColor}};">
      <span class="title"><p>{{topTitle}}</p></span>
            <div id="searchbox">
              <input-search placeholder="Search …"></input-search>
            </div>
            <paper-icon-button id="searchicon" icon="search" on-tap="openSearch"></paper-icon-button>

      <span class="middle title"><h1>{{middleTitle}}</h1></span>
      <span class="bottom title"><p class="subtitle">{{bottomTitle}}</p></span>
    </paper-toolbar>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'tool-bar',
      properties: {
        topTitle: String,
        middleTitle: String,
        bottomTitle: String,
        toolbarSize: String,
        toolbarColor: String
      },
      openSearch: function() {
        var sb = document.getElementById("searchbox");
        console.log(sb);
        if (sb.hasAttribute("hidden")) {
          sb.removeAttribute("hidden");
        } else {
          sb.setAttribute("hidden", true);
        }
      }
    });
</script>
```

This is the code that calls in in various other elements:

```
<paper-scroll-header-panel>
 <div class="paper-header staticpage">
  <tool-bar
    toolbar-color="var(--sc-gold-500)" 
    toolbar-size="tall" 
    middle-title="Titletext" 
    bottom-title="Subtitle text">
  </tool-bar>
 </div>
 <page-view></page-view>
</paper-scroll-header-panel>
```

When I open the site and click on the search icon, it indeed toggles the searchbox just fine. But when I go to any other page (a different element that calls the same toolbar with different attributes), it does not toggle the toolbar any more.

This looks to me like a bug but if anybody has a solution or explanation for this behavior, I'd be very grateful. I have tried it with various other input-elements and it has the same result.

**Output of the Console.log:**
The console.log seems to indicate that everything is fine.

On the first page (where the element hides/unhides correctly):
First click: `<div id="searchbox" class="style-scope tool-bar" hidden="true">`
Second click: `<div id="searchbox" class="style-scope tool-bar">`

Then I move to another page/element and it gives exactly the same results, except that the element does not hide, even when the attribute `hidden="true"`. When I look at the inspect element however, it does not show the attribute `hidden="true"`.

However, when I click it so the console.log says that `hidden="true"`, and then I move back to the first page/element, the searchbox is indeed hidden on that first page.

Comment: at first, you should add var when declaring `sb` variable. At second, when you add console.log(sb) after declaring variable and test it , what is the output from different elements. And last thing, you should add attribute via js function `sb.setAttribute("hidden", true)` but this is only cosmetic thing

Comment: Thanks. The lack of `var` was a typo here. I have corrected this and added your other suggestions and the output of the console.log to the question above. Any ideas what this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Polymer is based on Shadow-DOM, standard DOM selectors (such as `document.getElementById('someId')`) are ill-advised will lead to unexpected results. This is because a custom element will insert duplicate IDs into the DOM.

To overcome this, you must use Polymer's element selector method instead: `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#someId')`. This can be conveniently shortened to `this.$$.someId`. (where `this` is the custom element)

## The Fix

For your code as above, change the `openSearch` function to the following:

```
openSearch: function() {
  this.toggleAttribute('hidden', true, this.$.searchbox);
}
```

Thanks [@Kuba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3994868/kuba-%C5%A0imonovsk%C3%BD) for pointing out my initial error.

## Fix Explanation

#### Element Selection

`this.$` is an object of element IDs for the current custom element (`this`) when it was stamped onto the page. Therefore, `this.$.searchbox` gets the element's handle for **this** custom element's 'searchbox' element. This is in comparison to  `document.getElementById(...)`, which will only get the first element with `id="searchbox"` it finds on the page, not necessarily the one belonging to the current custom element.

#### Attribute Toggling

Polymer adds some special methods to it's element handles (that come from `PolymerBase`) for custom elements. One of these is the `PolymerBase.toggleAttribute(String name [, Boolean value, Element node])` method ([link to docs](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/polymer/1.0.0-rc.19/polymer.lib.polymer_micro/PolymerBase/toggleAttribute.html)). To use this method with a polymer element, you call it on the element's reference from `this.$` or `this.$$`.

For elements of a custom element, use:

- `this.toggleAttribute('hidden', true, this.$.someElementId)`

If the target element is a custom element loaded by polymer, you can also use:

- `this.$.someElementId.toggleAttribute('hidden')`
- `this.$.someElementId.toggleAttribute('hidden', true)`

*As a side note:* Please rename your toolbar to `vims-toolbar` or similar to follow the custom elements naming scheme of `<namespace>-<element-name>`.

*Further reading:* [PolymerBase docs](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/polymer/1.0.0-rc.19/polymer.lib.polymer_micro/PolymerBase-class.html#instance-methods)

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed explanation. The only problem is that the console now tells me: Uncaught TypeError: this.$.searchbox.toggleAttribute is not a function. But polymer is loaded via `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">` and that function exists.

Comment: @Vims function toggleAttribute does not exists in javascript. It's function of Polymer. So: `this.toggleAttribute("hidden", true|false, this.$.searchbox);`
Explanation above is invalid because this.$.searchbox doesn't point to Polymer element but to simple <span>

Comment: Thanks @kuba-Šimonovský for the fix. I'm used to using it directly on custom elements so accidentally used that code instead. I have amended the answer to work on generic elements.